# Create a wrapper for std algorithm functions to take container instead of iterators

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to create wrappers for the std functions that take begin and end iterators, so that they can also take a whole container. For example, something like

`std::for_each(mycont, FUNC)`

instead of

`std::for_each(mycont.begin(), mycont.end(), FUNC)`

I understand the benefits of separating algorithms and containers in general, but I often want to do something with the whole container and this syntax will be more convenient for me. If you don't agree, that's fine.

I tried the following but it doesn't compile

```
namespace stx
{
    template<class CONT, class FUNC, class ...Ts>
    void blah(CONT& cont, FUNC func, Ts... args)
    {
        func(cont.begin(), cont.end(), args...);
    }
}

struct Bob
{
    void stuff()
    {
    }
};

std::vector<Bob> bobs(3);
stx::blah(bobs, &std::for_each, &Bob::stuff);
```

`error C2783: 'void stx::blah(CONT &,FUNC,Ts...)' : could not deduce template argument for 'FUNC'`

What am I doing wrong? (VS2013)

Comment: for_each itself is a template function but compiler can't deduce it's parameters because there is no relation with it usage (actually you just pass a function pointer). You have to explictly specify template arguments or relate them somehow (not just FUNC but something related to CONT too).

Comment: Moreover, it's generally a bad idea to have a function pointer in parameter of a function. To achieve what you're trying to do and to manage overloaded algorithms, you will probably have to wrap them inside some functors.

Comment: You might want to consider the [Boost Range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/range/doc/html/index.html) library. It already defines algorithms that take a "range" parameter, and has adapters to treat a container as a range.

Comment: Unfortunately the way I wanted to do this (and you probably tried) was using a template-template argument through a functor, but alas template-template arguments must be classes (at least on my toolchain, clang 3.4), *not* functions, so even with a functor-wrap-around its a no-go as a generic solution. If I run across a way to do it, I'll post back, but it isn't looking promising.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`std::for_each`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) has a templated signature:

```
template< class InputIt, class UnaryFunction >
UnaryFunction for_each( InputIt first, InputIt last, UnaryFunction f );
```

You can't pass `std::for_each` as a function argument without specifying the template types for `std::for_each`. That is, you'd have to do:

```
stx::blah(bobs, &std::for_each<...>, &Bob::stuff);
```

Where you replace `...` with the correct template parameters for `std::for_each`.

Given that most `std` functions are templated, I consider your idea a bad idea. As much as I hate macros for most things, it's the only way I can think of escaping the static-type-and-template hell you're creating.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do what you've asked:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

namespace stx 
{
template<class C, class F>
F for_each(C const &c, F f) {
    return std::for_each(c.begin(), c.end(),f); 
}
}

void printone(int a)
{
    std::cout << ' ' << a;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v(10);
    std::iota(v.begin(), v.end(), 1);
    stx::for_each(v, printone);
    std::cout << '\n';
    std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), printone);
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

This prints:

```
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

which demonstrates the equivalence of the `std::for_each` and `stx::for_each`.

**Edit:** 
Note that I've used a C++11-ism `std::iota` but if you're using an older compiler, that line is equivalent to

```
    for (int i=0; i < 10; ++i)
        v[i] = i+1;
```

Comment: Thanks. That works for `for_each`, but I was trying to avoid creating a wrapper for every algorithm function.

Comment: Fair enough, but I think that ultimately it will be the cleanest solution.

Comment: you should take a container by a reference: template<class C, class F>
F for_each( C const& c, F f) {
    return std::for_each(c.begin(), c.end(),f); 
}

Comment: @privatedatapublicchannel2 Good point.  I'll update the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
#define OVERLOAD_SET(F)\
  static struct { template<typename... Args> \
    auto operator()(Args&&...args) const { \
      return F(std::forward<Args>(args)); \
    } \
  }
namespace stx {
  OVERLOAD_SET(std::foreach) for_each;
}
#undef OVERLOAD_SET
```

and now `stx::for_each` is a single object you can pass to other functions that does overload lookup on `std::for_each` statically.

This can be made fancier, and even include ADL snd implicit cast-to-function-pointer.

It does require creating an overload set object for each template function you want to treat this way.  Oh and I used a C++1y feature (return type deduction improvements) because I am lazy -- add the `decltype` if you need pure C++11.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you're trying to do and to manage overloaded algorithms, you have to forget about function pointers.

The closest solution to what you're trying to do would be :

```
#include <algorithm>

namespace stx {
    static struct {
        template <typename... Args>
        void operator()(Args&&... args) 
        {
            std::for_each(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        }
    }for_each;

    template<class Containter, typename Func, typename ...Args>
    void apply_on(Containter& c, Func func, Args... args)
    {
        func(c.begin(), c.end(), args...);
    }

    template<class Containter, typename... Args>
    auto for_each_on(Containter& c, Args... args)
        -> decltype(apply_on(c, for_each, args...))
    {
        return apply_on(c, for_each, args...);
    }
}

#include <functional> // C++11 or C++14 std::mem_fn
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct Bob {
    void stuff()
    {
        std::cout << "stuffing..." << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Bob> bobs(3);

    // Now you can do :
    stx::apply_on(bobs, stx::for_each,  std::mem_fn(&Bob::stuff));
    // or
    stx::for_each_on(bobs, std::mem_fn(&Bob::stuff));

    return 0;
}
```

Providing a wrapper "for each" algorithm has been done [here](http://ideone.com/aruf06). You should also have a look at [Boost.Range algorithms](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/algorithms/introduction.html). This could be what you are really looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This could be used

```
 template <typename containerT, typename FunctionT>
    FunctionT for_all(containerT cont,
                FunctionT func)
    {
        typename containerT::iterator first = cont.begin();
        typename containerT::iterator last = cont.end();
        for (;first != last; ++first)
            func(*first);
        return func;
    }
```